# jquery ui modal window: normal radio button or select elements don't respond to click

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I call a jQuery UI dialog and set `modal: false`, I can click on normal (non-UI) html radio buttons **inside the dialog** with no problem.

But when `modal: true`, then the radio buttons **inside the dialog** don't respond to click events.

Is there a simple explanation for this behavior?

Answer (score 1):

The point of a modal dialog is so that the users focus is drawn to the information you are displaying to them. When `modal: true` is set, the focus is on the modal form. The rest of the page is effectively disabled until the user has closed the dialog. This is why the click events don't fire. Usually the background behind the dialog is greyed out so make it clear that the area is basically inactive.

By setting `modal: false` your form options in the background and the modal forms options are all enabled. So if `modal: true` is set, only radio buttons etc are enabled on the modal dialog.

Here's a few demos which you can click form controls to see when they are disabled. An active radio/checkbox click results in an alert.

[**Demo: Modal: true**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSEaw/2/)

[**Demo: Modal: false**](http://jsfiddle.net/KSEaw/1/)

Comment: Thanks, I'm aware setting modal: true disables the background html. That's not my issue. My issue is that the radio buttons INSIDE the modal dialog are not functioning.

Comment: Could you post your code? I can get the click event to fire within a modal dialog (see updated demo Modal:true above). I thought I had an alert firing within it when I originally posted but it seems I didn't.